# PostgreSQL connection in Java Servlet to Retrieve Information from the DB. Getting Error

Tags: java, postgresql, connect

I am having difficulty with getting this work. I can connect to the database without problem, however I can not make it show me the html page. It does not run.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class ShowBedrock extends HttpServlet 
{
    public String getServletInfo()
    {
       return "Servlet connects to PostgreSQL database and displays result of a SELECT";
    }

    private Connection dbcon;  // Connection for scope of ShowBedrock

    // "init" sets up a database connection
    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException
    {
        String loginUser = "postgres";
        String loginPasswd = "supersecret";
        String loginUrl = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost/bedrock";

        // Load the PostgreSQL driver
        try 
        {
              Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
              dbcon = DriverManager.getConnection(loginUrl, loginUser, loginPasswd);
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException ex)
        {
               System.err.println("ClassNotFoundException: " + ex.getMessage());
               throw new ServletException("Class not found Error");
        }
        catch (SQLException ex)
        {
               System.err.println("SQLException: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    // Use http GET

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws IOException, ServletException
    {
        response.setContentType("text/html");    // Response mime type

        // Output stream to STDOUT
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        out.println("<HTML><Head><Title>Bedrock</Title></Head>");
        out.println("<Body><H1>Bedrock</H1>");

        try
        {
                // Declare our statement
                Statement statement = dbcon.createStatement();

                String query = "SELECT name, dept, ";
                query +=       "       jobtitle ";
                query +=       "FROM   employee ";

                // Perform the query
                ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(query);

                out.println("<table border>");

                // Iterate through each row of rs
                while (rs.next())
                {
                   String m_name = rs.getString("name");
                   String m_dept = rs.getString("dept");
                   String m_jobtitle = rs.getString("jobtitle");
                   out.println("<tr>" + 
                               "<td>" + m_name + "</td>" +
                               "<td>" + m_dept + "</td>" +
                               "<td>" + m_jobtitle + "</td>" +
                               "</tr>");
                }

                out.println("</table></body></html>");
                statement.close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
                out.println("<HTML>" +
                            "<Head><Title>" +
                            "Bedrock: Error" +
                            "</Title></Head>\n<Body>" +
                            "<P>SQL error in doGet: " +
                            ex.getMessage() + "</P></Body></HTML>");
                return;
        }
        out.close();
    }
}
```

I get the following error any body knows why?:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Class not found Error
    ShowBedrock.init(ShowBedrock.java:42)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)


note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/6.0.35 logs.
```

Comment: While this isn't an answer, I do have a suggestion: Don't use the PostgreSQL JDBC driver directly. Use a connection pool like C3P0, proxool, etc. In EE application servers one is built in and provided for you by the app server; I don't know if that's the case in Tomcat. You'll have a lot less trouble with resource waste and connection overhead if you use a connection pool.

Comment: Don't use `ex.getMessage()` but `ex.printStackTrace()`. Or better use Log4J or some similar library for logging your errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I get the following error any body knows why?

The reason why you are getting that error body is that your handler for `ClassNotFoundException` is **throwing away** the original exception stacktrace.  You are writing the original exception's message to `System.err` but (obviously) that won't go into the normal system logs.  (You'll probably find find the message in the "catalina.out" file ... depending on how Tomcat is configured / launched.)

The right way to do this is to either chain the exception; e.g.

```
    throw new ServletException("Class not found Error", e);
```

or log it explicitly at the point that you catch it.  And if you do log it explicitly, make sure that you log the exception, and not just the exception message.

---

We can't tell you the actual root cause of the problem unless we see the original exception stacktrace ... but the two most likely causes are:

- The classloader can't find a class that is needed; e.g. because the JAR file is not in the right place.
- Class initialization failed for some class during the initialization of the class that you are attempting to load.

Answer (score 1):

Tomcat expects that your servlet will be in a package.  Yours appears to be in the default package; please add one and recompile.  I'll bet things will go better for you then.

Tomcat 6 and 7 expect to find JDBC JARs in the server /lib directory.  Add your PostgreSQL JDBC JAR to the server /lib location.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I tried it, did not do the trick and all my servlets work in default package without any problems.

Comment: I forgot to do it and this comment saved my life! Thank you.

Comment: Glad to help.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Seem you did't add Postgresql JDBC driver into classpath, as the following error suggest:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Class not found Error
```

Which is origin from:

```
throw new ServletException("Class not found Error");
```

You can [download](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html) Postgresql JDBC driver and put in `PROJECT/WEB-INF/lib` folder.

**Suggestion**

One suggestion, your exception handling is wrong, you should change

```
throw new ServletException("Class not found Error");
```

to

```
throw new ServletException("Class not found Error", e);
```

Comment: But, it is there in WEB-INF/lib